# jquery insert html in every page body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to find a way to insert the html on every page just below the body tag via jQuery.

This is my html:

```
<nav class="nav">
<ul class="centered">
            <li>
        <a href="/it_IT/home" class="progressiveBorder">HOME PAGE</a>
    </li>
</nav>
```

This is my jquery

```
jQuery( "body" ).append( "<nav class="nav"><ul class="centered"><li><a href="/it_IT/home" class="progressiveBorder">HOME PAGE</a></li></nav>" );
```

But it does not work, it does not return anything to me on the page.

Has anyone done something like that?

Comment: You need to escape your double quotes `"` in your HTML String. Like this `\"`

Comment: Thanks... my mistake, thank you very much

Comment: @LucaBelletti Use a mix of single and double quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is with your string:

```
jQuery( "body" ).append( "<nav class="nav"><ul class="centered"><li><a href="/it_IT/home" class="progressiveBorder">HOME PAGE</a></li></nav>" );
```

You either need to escape the double quotes or use single quotes to stop the string from "stopping"/"ending":

```
jQuery( "body" ).append( "<nav class='nav'><ul class='centered'><li><a href='/it_IT/home' class='progressiveBorder'>HOME PAGE</a></li></nav>" );
```

Here I have used single quotes as I find it easier to read. For future reference you can escape a double quote by doing `"\""`. The backslash indicates the the `"` is part of the string, and not to stop the string at that point, but rather to include it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `\` before your double quotes in a string:

```
jQuery( "body" ).append( "<nav class=\"nav\"><ul class=\"centered\"><li><a href=\"/it_IT/home\" class=\"progressiveBorder\">HOME PAGE</a></li></nav>" );
```

Comment: Or use a mix of single and double quotes.